# How to use path and query parameters together for an API request

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests

I need to call an API request by **mixing path and query parameters**.

Two path parameters is required to use, query parameters are optional. I use the following url to run API call and get successful result:

**/network/trace/{a_point_vetro_id}/{z_point_vetro_id}**

However when I added a query parameter (plan_ids) into the link above. I couldnt get any result.

I tried many way to implement it, unfortunately, no dice

I tried following url requests and many others

- /network/trace/2c0eb535-faaf-4c55-b6b8-25866e9eea44/3bf563f3-b3b2-462b-836a-abcb867ae4a6/get?plan_ids=499
- /network/trace/2c0eb535-faaf-4c55-b6b8-25866e9eea44/3bf563f3-b3b2-462b-836a-abcb867ae4a6/query?plan_ids=499

Here is the documentation for the API call:

**https://fibermap.vetro.io/documentation/#get-trace**

I'm using python requests if that's matter.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem wasn't actually the code. I used wrong plan_id and API returned zero result

For future reference here is the URL request I used for path and query parameters together

https://fibermap.uk.vetro.io/v2/network/trace/2c0eb535-faaf-4c55-b6b8-25866e9eea44/3bf563f3-b3b2-462b-836a-abcb867ae4a6?plan_ids=1414